# how we can prove that the Variance of (white Gussian noise) is average power of the noise?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications

White Gaussian Noise PSD is fixed No/2. So how we can investigate that noise variance is average power of the noise?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is clearly a homework question: 
Simply by applying the definition of variance. Remember that white noise has a mean of 0.